# I can't get all images from database Only single Image get from database

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, foreach

**This is my model look**

```
public function fetchimage(){
        $this->db->select('u_id,file_name');
        $this->db->from('image');
        if($this->session->userdata('id')){
            $this->db->where('u_id',$this->session->userdata('id'));
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $query->result_array();
            $result = $query->row_array();
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($query);
            die();
        }
        return !empty($result)?$result:false;
    }
```

**This is my view look**

```
<?php 
            $this->load->model('user');
            $data['uploadData'][] = $this->user->fetchimage();
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="gallery">
                    <?php if($data['uploadData']){ foreach($data['uploadData'] as $data['uploadData']){
                    ?>
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/uploads/files/'.$data['uploadData']['file_name']); ?>" >
                    </li>
                    <?php } }else{ ?>
                    <p>Image(s) not found.....</p>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div><br>
```

The images is not printing all. It's Printing only one Image. While i take foreach loop.
In Model i print query and that is print all images but in view it's not printing images.

Comment: update $data['uploadData'][] = $this->user->fetchimage() to $data['uploadData'] = $this->user->fetchimage() and check it once

Comment: i tried but it shown error **illegal string offset of file_name**

Comment: What happens if you remove the code `echo '<pre>';  print_r($query);   die();`?

Comment: it shows only one image not all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

> `row_array()` will give you single row with an array of array format and `result_array()` will give you multiple rows with an array of array format.

```
public function fetchimage(){
        $this->db->select('u_id,file_name');
        $this->db->from('image');
        if($this->session->userdata('id')){
            $this->db->where('u_id',$this->session->userdata('id'));
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result_array();
            echo '<pre>';print_r($query);die();
        }
        return !empty($result)?$result:false;
    }
```

View :

```
<?php
$this->load->model('user');
$data['uploadData'] = $this->user->fetchimage();
?>
<div class="row">
     <ul <?php if ($data['uploadData']) {
           foreach ($data['uploadData'] as $rowData) { ?>
               <li class="item">
                   <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/uploads/files/' .$rowData['file_name']); ?>" >
               </li>
           <?php } } else { ?>
           <p>Image(s) not found.....</p>
         <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: i already try this and it is shown all data but in view mode it is not showing data. it is showing only one image

Comment: remove last [] brackets from `$data['uploadData'][] and try

Comment: i tried but it shown error **illegal string offset 'file_name'**

Comment: just updated you foreach loop please check and tell me